# nodejs: $lte for date is not working as expected in mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb

As the question explains, I am trying to query on dates and the result is not as expected. Here is the how the objects, that I am trying to query, look like:

```
{
"_id":{"$oid":"5f660cfcde436c3035b59648"},
"orderid":"2020-09-19-8939",
"orderdate":"2021-08-09T11:02:31.202+00:00",
"paycondition_ref":{"$oid":"5f211e9690e310990ea6aa5d"},
"receivedate":{"$date":"2020-09-22T05:59:38.211Z"},
"duedate":"2020-09-19T13:51:56.219Z",
"currency":{"$oid":"5f660cfcde436c3035b59647"},
"supplier_ref":{"$oid":"5f2e12286b15925440f03b56"},
"history":false,
"remark":"Clarance - Tuesday"
}
```

And here is how I am querying it:

```
"$match": {
       "$and": [
          { 'purchaseorder.orderdate': { $gte: new Date(startDate), $lte: new Date(endDate) } },
          { 'purchaseorder.history': false },
        ]
}
```

And the `startDate` and `endDate` objects look like this:

```
startDate 2021-08-08T19:00:00.000Z
endDate 2021-08-08T19:00:00.000Z
```

This should return the object above, shouldn't it? But it doesn't! What am I doing wrong here? How can I resolve this?

Comment: The syntax doesn't look right. You may want to refer the MongoDB NodeJS Driver manual.

Comment: Also, in order to do queries like that, your orderdate field should be of type DATE, like your receivedate field. If it's not a field of type DATE, you're trying to use a $lte in a string...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your data object and query I noticed two things,

1. Why are you fetching data using `purchaseorder.orderdate and purchaseorder.history'`. You can directly access field
2. You are storing the date fields as `string` instead of `date` type, that is the reason comparison won't work when you do `new Date` . Change that schema to hold date field as type of `date`
3. Also you are storing dates in local Time Zone, so when comparing you should not use UTC to match your existing date. To make it simple it is always recommended to store dates in UTC TZ.

The following comparisons work for me:

```
    db.getCollection("test-code").aggregate({
    "$match": {
      'orderdate':
          { $gte: new Date("2021-08-08T16:32:31.202+05:30"), $lte: new Date("2021-08-10T16:32:31.202+05:30") },
      'history': false,
    }
})
```

Note: I have used local TZ and my fields were of type date in DB `2021-08-10T16:32:31.202+05:30`

Answer (score 0):

use ISODate instead of new Date and remove "purchaseorder"

```
"$match": {
       "$and": [
          { 'orderdate': { $gte: ISODate(startDate), $lte: ISODate(endDate) } },
          { 'history': false },
        ]
}
```